# polidy VCF file for Canvas somatic-wgs cnv calling

Tags: wgs, illumina, cnv, somatic

I am trying to run Illumina CANVAS cnv caller for Somatic-WGS. There is an option "--ploidy-vcf" which is mandatory to supply, but don't know what exactly that mean. I had supplied the CNV.vcf file from the germline WGS (matched normal run on Canvas smallPedigree), but it has given an error that says "Reference copy number > 2 is not supported" at the last stage of run.

I would like to know your experience when you used CANVAS on somatic WGS samples. What ploidy-file is appropriate here? Should it be only chrX and Y in it? Your suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to supply vcf files specifying the ploidy of the sex chromosomes.

See https://github.com/Illumina/canvas/issues/89 for explanation and example vcf files.